# Notification notify() wrong arguments

Tags: android, android-notifications

I building a notifiaction with NotificationCompat.Builder and to show it I need to notify NotificationManager about new notifation, so I'm calling

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(SOME_INT_NUMBER, builder.build());
```

but eclipse marks "notif(..)" as error with caption:

> The method notify() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (int, Notification)

And I'm pretty sure notif(int, Notification) exists:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I discovered also I can't import android.app.NotificationManager, due to:

> The import android.app.NotificationManager conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Comment: Clean your project. Then it should works.

Comment: @Sajmon Already tried that... no result.

Comment: @Sajmon in end your answer was partially correct - look at post which is chosen as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Notification Compat Builder and Notification Manager to generate notifications and it works just fine for me. Pasting the working code below, check if you have missed out something:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

 final int notificationID = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
 final int icon = R.drawable.nf_notification;
 final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(title).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentIntent(intent).setAutoCancel(true).setContentText(message);
 notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
```

Comment: then it means ,its a problem while building your project..try cleaning and building your project.

Comment: I already tried that few times... but when I created new project and just pasted that there It worked... Damn eclipse and cleaning&building projects, I will have to import project once more or something. Thx.